# Allow extra parameter for has_many through join table with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

My models are setup as follows:

```
class Contract <ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contract_upgrades
  has_many :upgrades, through: :contract_upgrades
end
```

My Upgrade model

```
class Upgrade < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contract_upgrades
  has_many :contracts, through: :contract_upgrades
end
```

my ContractUpgrade model

```
# schema
  t.integer :contract_id
  t.integer :upgrade_id
  t.integer :qty
class ContractUpgrade < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contract
  belongs_to :upgrade
end
```

My contract form looks like this...

```
- @upgrades.available.each do |upgrade|
  %tr{class: "#{upgrade.id}", id: 'upgrade-checkboxes'}
    %td
      .upgrade-checkboxes
        = check_box_tag "contract[upgrade_ids][]", upgrade.id, @contract.upgrades.include?(upgrade), { upgrade_id: upgrade.id }
        = label_tag "contract_upgrade_#{upgrade.id}", upgrade.name
    %td
      = number_to_currency("#{upgrade.price}")
  - if upgrade.allow_each
```

here is where it gets a little tricky...

```
    %td
      %input{type: 'text', placeholder: 'Qty'} # displays text_field box
      = number_field_tag # displays text_field box
```

When the upgrade check_box is checked the upgrade.id and contract.id save as it should and works perfectly.  I need to be able to input a quantity on those upgrades that can have multiple.  In my Contracts controller the upgrade_ids are whitelisted via {upgrade_ids: []}, and no matter what I've done whenever anything is in the qty field I get an unpermitted_parameter :qty...

***UPDATE***

I'd be able to figure out what/how to do what I essentially need to do if someone can get [Rails Guides Associations: has_many_through example](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) to work.  In this example directly from the rails guides the join table has an appointment_date attribute.

Comment: You can define `accepts_nested_attributes_for :contract_upgrades` in `Contract` model, and define `f.fields_for` in form, and in `Contracts` controller you can `.permit(quantities_attributes: [])`

Comment: Please have a look at this screencast for nested forms. It will go through it step by step: http://www.amooma.de/screencasts/2015-01-22-nested_forms-rails-4.2/